# fabric.js in Angular 4 application produces warning

Tags: angular, fabricjs

Running fabric.js in Angular 4 application produces the following warning, in both development and production environment.

```
./node_modules/fabric/dist/fabric.js
25971:14-42 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an 
expression
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From [webpack's GitHub issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/196#issuecomment-71917456):

> This error [...] usually means that *every* file below a certain path will be included into the bundle (which should certainly not be ignored).

From [the same thread](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/196#issuecomment-37350730),

> [This error] is simply warning about a dependency written as an expression.

In [other words](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/196#issuecomment-213594443):

> [T]here is a dynamic import here and dynamic imports should not be used.

[Summary](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/196#issuecomment-354996438):

> [W]hile webpack is a great resource for statically bundling imports, this issue arises when a 3rd-party library uses a `require()` expression to e.g. load a JSON or JS config file at runtime.

You can also [track the GitHub issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/196).

Answer (score 0):

The canvas dependency can be either canvas or canvas-prebuilt

that depends on the value of the property in the fabric main object used to pick up one or the other package.

those dependency are nodejs only and you should not be worried about webpack picking them up since are set to false in the browser section of package.json